# OpenLayers 4.6.5 addLayer circular structure & layer.getLayerArray is not a function

Tags: openlayers

Currently working with OL 4.6.5 and Angular 6 and for the life of me have read the documentation and API references on the OL site http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/doc/

And despite following there examples of how to add layers such as

````
  var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({source: osmSource});
  map.addLayer(osmLayer);

  @Input( 'coreMap' ) coreMap;
  vector : VectorLayer;
  source;
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.coreMap);
    console.log(this.coreMap.layerManager);```

      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.layer.Vector(),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 2
          }),
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: '#ffcc33'
            })
          })
        })
      });
      this.vector = vector;
    }
  addLayer(){
    this.coreMap.map.addLayer(this.vector)
  }
````

The coreMap being the base level of the map (It was created by someone else on the project so I'm picking up from how they have set it up)

I can see elsewhere they have written it like so

```
this.coreMap.layerManager.addLayer( this.drawLayer )
```

Which I've also tried and yielding the same result of circular structure error & layer.getLayerArray is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

So after delving into the source code I've managed to actually add the layer like so.

```
  @Input( 'coreMap' ) coreMap :CoreMapComponent
  vector : VectorLayer;
  ngOnInit(){
    var source = new VectorSource({wrapX: false});
    var style = new Style({
      geometry: 'circle',
      fill: new Fill({
        color: 'red'
      }),
      stroke: new Stroke({
        color: 'red',
        width: 5
      })
    })
      var vector = new VectorLayer({
        source: source,
        style: style
      });
  this.vector = vector;
    }
  addLayer(){
    this.coreMap.layerManager.addLayer(this.vector);
  }

  getLayers(){
    console.log(this.coreMap.map.getLayers().getArray());
  }
```

The tutorials on the ol site are somewhat vague and misleading at least in my case or not on par with there version numbers, shame I did make a mistake on assigning ol.layer.vector twice on the original code block rather than ol.source.vector on the second instance although that still didn't seem to rectify the issue.